# When calling my screen goes black on LG P880

Tags: calls, screen, lg-optimus-4x

After updating in Android 4.1.2 my screen goes black. Screen works again only when the call is finished.
I know about the feature when you put the phone on ear it goes black and the second you remove the phone from your ear , the screen turns on again. 
But now is different. Now it goes black the same second when I press call and there's nothing that brings it back until the call is over!
Please help.

Comment: It sounds like your proximity sensor is either broken or blocked. Do you have a screen protector? If the screen protector isn't decent enough or have a spot cut out for the proximity sensor, it would disable the screen as soon as a call is started (because it thinks it is next to your ear since it is blocked). This can also happen if your screen over the proximity sensor is extremely dirty. The other option is that your sensor is defective. As far as I know, there isn't much that can be done for this.

Comment: I don't have any screen protector. More often screen goes black other times it remain on and even if I cover the sensor it remains on.I'm not sure there's something with proximity sensor. This occurred right after upgrade of Android.

Comment: It works! All I had to do is to calibrate proximity sensor. From hiden menu (dial 3845#*880#) > Device Test -> All Auto Test Menu Full -> ALC / Proximity Test.

Comment: @Patrick Please don't add a comment just to say thanks. You have enough rep to upvote questions and answers if you find them helpful, which is our way of saying thanks.

Comment: How do you end your call?

Answer (score 1):

Based from [OP's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44462/when-calling-my-screen-goes-black-on-lg-p880#comment60160_44462), you have to calibrate the proximity sensor:

1. Go to "Secret Menu" by dialing `3845#*880#`
2. Select "Device Test"
3. Select "All Auto Test Menu Full"
4. Choose "ALC / Proximity Test"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my *LG Optimus 4X P880*: whenever I wanted to make a call, the screen was going to off position; only after finishing the call it turned back on.

I think it is nothing but a software problem in Android version 4.1.2. So I rolled back from 4.1.2 Jelly Bean to 4.0.3 Icecream Sandwich. Now my phone is working properly.